# Extracting data from nested lists

Tags: python-3.x, nested-lists

I am trying to extract data from a nested list (in python) in the exact order. For example:

```
lst=[1,[10,20,[100,200,300,400,500],40,50,60,70,80,90],3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

should throw:

```
1
10
20
100
200
300
400
500
40
50
60
70
80
90
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Can anyone help me with this problem?